# VLOOKUP () function in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce

According to the documentation, there is a function in VisualForce called VLOOKUP:

VLOOKUP(field_to_return, field_on_lookup_object, lookup_value) and replace field_to_return with the field that contains the value you want returned, field_on_lookup_object with the field on the related object that contains the value you want to match, and lookup_value with the value you want to match.

I have not seen any examples out there on how to use this.  Does anyone have such an example?

Comment: The only time I've seen it used is on a VF page that displayed the Name of the Parent Account related to the Account, related to the current activity.  I will add that it also seemed very unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Where in the documentation does it say that you can use VLOOKUP() in VF? As far as I know, this is limited to validation rules: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP

(See the last bulletpoint for confirmation.)

Comment: Here you go: 

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm

Comment: Sounds like a documentation bug to me - the other doc is very specific that VLOOKUP() only works for validation rules.